# Using a custom map gui disables the ability to save

Tags: rpg-maker

I'm quite confused at the moment. I've created a custom gui (a fuel display on map) that works nicely, but somehow whenever I try to save the game when this gui is active....clicking on the slot where I want to save the game does **not** work!

thus when I add the following code and let it be called via a trigger (a common event which has a switch as trigger calls this javascript code...event runs parallel with a wait (5)):

```
REITD.SpaceClass.prototype.showCargoAndFuelStatusUI = function (vehicleType, currentCargo, maxCargo, currentFuel, maxFuel) {
    if (!(SceneManager._scene instanceof Scene_Menu)) {
        if ($gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"] !== undefined) {
            SceneManager._scene.removeChild($gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"]);
        }

        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"] = new Window_Base(new Rectangle(1, 1, 211, 200));
        SceneManager._scene.addChild($gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"]);

        $gameSystem._REITD_shownStatusUIWindows["CargoAndFuel"] = "shown";

        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].drawText("Vehicle Fuel", 1, 5, 190, "center");
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].contents.fillRect(1, 40, 200, 25, _Colors.gray);
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].contents.fillRect(1, 40, 2 * this.calcFuelPercent(vehicleType), 25, _Colors.blue);  // 2 px per percent full.
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].drawText(
            padLeft(this.getCurrentFuel(vehicleType), 6, "0") + " / " + padLeft(this.getMaxFuel(vehicleType), 6, "0"), 30, 35, 100, "left");

        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].drawText("Vehicle Cargo", 1, 75, 190, "center");
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].contents.fillRect(1, 110, 200, 25, _Colors.gray);
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].contents.fillRect(1, 110, 2 * this.calcCargoPercent(vehicleType), 25, _Colors.red);  // 2 px per percent full.
        $gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"].drawText(
            padLeft(this.getCurrentCargo(vehicleType), 6, "0") + " / " + padLeft(this.getMaxCargo(vehicleType), 6, "0"), 30, 105, 100, "left");
    }
}
```

update: Even when I call a method to deactivate the custom gui....saving is still not possible:

```
REITD.SpaceClass.prototype.hideStatusUI = function (uiType) {
    if (uiType in $gameSystem._REITD_shownStatusUIWindows && $gameSystem._REITD_shownStatusUIWindows[uiType] == "shown") {
        //  Status UI exists => hide it!
        SceneManager._scene.removeChild($gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows[uiType]);
        $gameSystem._REITD_shownStatusUIWindows[uiType] = "";
    }
}
```

Also what I noticed...deactivating just the adding to the scene is enough to eliminate the problem (but means no custom gui being active):   //SceneManager._scene.addChild($gameSystem._REITD_definedWindows["CargoAndFuel"]);  => no problem. Thus somehow this part starts the problem and I don't understand why

I'm running into the problem.
Now my question is:
Why is that so and what can I do to correct this problem (or can I somehow deactivate this while a menu is open?)

Engine: RPGMaker MZ